# Generate Daily Agenda for Multiple Calendars?

Tags: google-calendar

I know how to generate a Daily Agenda for a single calendar; however, I'd like to receive a Daily Agenda for multiple calendars. Is that possible in the native web application? Is it possible using an add-on or Google Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

There used to be an extra option for that a few years back but it is now removed.

What you can do though is set up notifications for your other calendars one by one just as you set them for your main one.

- Click on the left hand wheel and choose `Settings`.
- Choose the `Calendars` tab.
- Next to the calendar you want added, select `General Notifications`.
- Check `Daily Agenda` and set your `Notifications` for this calendar.
- Enjoy!

In your next coming email, the new agend will be included.

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.